# Nextjs application cannot load scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, next.js, github-actions

I built a Next.js application which works perfect locally.
I deploy it on AWS.

I try to access it using my ALB on AWS, but I see the following errors in the console:
[image]

When I run locally "yarn run build" and then "yarn run start" it works perfect.

So why could it happen?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN yarn install --immutable --immutable-cache --check-cache

ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY ./ .

RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

My github action:

```
name: Deploy to AWS Fargate with major version

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - PRODUCTION

env:
  AWS_REGION: eu-west-1
  ECR_REPOSITORY: landing-page
  ECS_SERVICE: landing-page-service
  ECS_CLUSTER: landing-page
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: landing-page

  CONTAINER_NAME: landing-page

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: |
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

      - name: Download task definition
        run: |
          aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${{ env.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }} --query taskDefinition > task-definition.json

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
        id: task-def
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: task-definition.json
          container-name: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

      - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition with service
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: ${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}
          cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          wait-for-service-stability: true
```

By the way, at first I had `.next` in `.dockerignore` file so I thought it may cause issues, but I removed it and issues preserved.

I am running Fargate on AWS with and ALB - that's all.

What may went wrong?

I am able to get the website:
[image]

But just the "initial" of it.
CSS, images, js.. are not fully loaded.

Comment: what is the status of health check?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra
of what? ALB? FARGATE SERVICE?

Note my additional edited image. The website intial works..

Comment: how are you accesing your website ( image one) and yes health check of ALB target group

Comment: @JatinMehrotra
I know my ALB and Fargate machines are active and working because I can access my Load balance domain.. I do see my webiste, but missing all the JS & CSS files (I also get response from Postman)

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this issue by creating a SSL Certificate for my website and update it with the load balancer.

For me it satisfies.